# Which packages are automatically included by memoir?

Tags: packages, memoir

I am currently including:

```
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[stretch=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{verbatim}
```

Which of these can I remove?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is written to the log file or check the manual Section 18.24:

> memoir does include code from several packages and uses a similar internal command to ensure that the packages are not loaded following some later \usepackage command. The names of the emulated packages are written to the log file. At the time of writing the emulated packages are: abstract, appendix, array, booktabs, ccaption, chngcntr, crop, dcol- umn, delarray, enumerate, epigraph, ifmtarg, ifpdf, index, makeidx, moreverb, needspace, newfile, nextpage, pagenote, patchcmd, parskip, setspace, shortvrb, showidx, tabularx, ti- tleref, tocbibind, tocloft, verbatim, and verse. As well as the emulated packages memoir provides functions equivalent to those in the following packages, although the class does not prevent you from using them: fancyhdr, framed, geometry, sidecap, subfigure, and ti- tlesec.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from reading the documentation (which you should always do, although in the case of memoir it can be intimidating), you always have the option to check the log file: it reports all the names of the files it includes in brackets, with their nesting levels; hence you would have something like:

```
(.../memoir.sty (.../somepackage.sty) [etc.])
```

This is only a hypothetical example, as according to the documentation quoted by Leo, many packages are actually not included at all, but have their code embedded into memoir.